# Open a file and write to 2nd column a certain number

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to open file 1 which has the following format

```
20336
20337
20338
.
.
.
71644
71645
71646
```

and write to second column number 20336 so the new file will have the following format

```
20336 20336
20337 20336
20338 20336
.     .
.     .
.     .
71644 20336
71645 20336
71646 20336
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{print $0,"20336"}' input
```

To create a new file with the output simply redirect like so:

```
awk '{print $0,"20336"}' input > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the end with sed:

```
sed -i -e 's/$/ 20336/g' yourfile
```

Comment: Are you aware that `-ie` will cause the original file to be backed up as `yourfilee` ? Perhaps you intended `sed -i -e ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
<in >out \
sed /'\./!s/$/ 20336/;s//& &/'
```

if a trailing space after the 20336 doesnt bother...